# How a multicore processor is initialized?

Tags: microprocessor, processor

Is there any general protocol or algorithm to start a multicore processor? If so, how it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058148/how-multicore-processors-boot

Generally, the CPU designated "0" boots from a reset vector in the normal manner. Once it's initialised the interrupt controller, it sends an interrupt to the other processors, causing them to start from that interrupt vector.

Comment: That magic excerpt _is_ limited to Intel though, whereas this question is tagged microprocessor as well.

Comment: Well, in general there are only two possibilities: (a) all processors start running or (b) one starts running with the others suspended. If (a), then the writer of the boot ROM has to do more synchronisation work. This document says the ARM boot sequence is basically the same, starting in WFI: http://www.linux-arm.org/pub/LinuxPlatform/RealViewLink/Booting_ARM_Linux_SMP_on_MPCore.doc

Comment: (Consider also what happens if you have multiple processors running during a handover from bootloader to operating system: all processors need to transition at the same time.)

Comment: When running Linux, they do. There are multitudes of single and multi core embedded controllers that go into Maincode sequence with with a reset state. If then main code is an operating system this will include some kind of boot loading first, but if it isn't, it might not, leaving activation and loading of code, etc to the main code. If the question is "how do I boot a multicore processor system with an OS", fair enough. This just asks "How does a multicore (micro--implied--)processor start"

Answer (score 1):

That is highly dependent on the exact multi-core processor.

The old Playstation 2 allowed you to offload snippets from the first core to the second, both already being clocked.

Some embedded ARM multicore designs require you to load instruction code into the memory segment of the other cores through a set of instructions on the primary core.

PC Multicores are more flexible, but often the Bios/OS starts off core 0 and then starts offloading parts of its execution to other cores, but technically that's not the work of the first core, it could be the process on core 0 spins up the core 1 process, where core 1 spins up 2, etc, but usually it's the main thread running on C0 that handles all the branching off and such.